# SQL unit tests with Visual Studio Ultimate trial and Express editions

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Wanted to ask (this is the primary question):

- whether there is a possibility to unit test SQL stored procedures with VS 2012 / 2013 Express edition (maybe an indirect, inconvenient way - that would also be fine). The resources on the internet indicate that: "First you must have Visual Studio 2010 or 2012 Professional edition or higher installed." ([link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/12/07/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-unit-testing-in-ssdt.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20ssdtblog%20(SQL%20Server%20Developer%20Tools%20Team%20Blog))). for the SSDT to have the "create unit tests" button when you place your mouse on s stored procedure in the SQL server object explorer in VS. However if I install the Trial version of VS 2013 Ultimate I still do not see this option.
- This is my second question: why not? Is this disabled in trial version?
- The last question is on whether there is some way for writing SQL SProc unit tests with other tools that would still have integration with TFS, SQL Server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in the express editions that is blocking the SQL unit test template from finding its expected resources. This means that when you try to create unit tests for a function or stored procedure, or even create a blank SQL unit test file in a C#/VB test project, this will fail to as it can't find the templates. However if you already have a project with SQL Unit Test files created you will be able to run those tests fine. It's creation that's currently blocked. My recommendation would be to open a connect bug for this issue at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx and use the category "Developer Tools(SSDT, BIDS, etc.)". That can help raise the priority of this issue and ensure it'll be assessed by the product team.

Note that some reasons this might not be working for you in VS2013 Ultimate are:

- You are right-clicking on a stored procedure in a connected database. Creation of unit tests is currently supported for elements inside projects only. In SQL Server Object Explorer you need to browse to Projects -> Project Name -> Programmability. Right-clicking there will show "Create Unit Tests" if there are any supported objects. Note that if you've updated to the latest tooling (Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates -> SQL Server tooling update) you can also right-click on a file in Solution Explorer, and if it has any testable elements you will see "Create Unit Tests" as an option.
- Your project must build in order for unit test creation to be supported. If it's not in a clean state (build runs with no errors) then Create Unit Tests will be disabled.